# How to wrap access to struct members without changing user code?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a series of structs that are globally accessible, and must remain so for legacy reasons. Similarly, there is code in numerous places that is accessing the members of that struct (and members of those members, where applicable). I cannot practically change the calling code in the 100s of places, but I would like to somehow intercept the access in order to control it, e.g. using asserts to help insure thread safety when threading this legacy code.

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int a;
    char b;
    float c;
};

struct GlobalStruct
{
    MyStruct myStruct;
};

// Random example/mock-up calling code
void SomeFunction()
{
    GlobalStruct* globals = GetGlobals();
    globals->myStruct = MyStruct {
        // ...
    };
    
    // ...
    
    globals->myStruct.a = 10;
    
    const float res = SomeCalculation(globals.myStruct);
    globals->myStruct.c = res;
}
```

In this example, I want to be able to intercept the accesses in SomeFunction to MyStruct's members, or to the MyStruct instance itself.

Because it's stored by value, we can't use `->` operator overloading to intercept. I tried using the following wrapper class:

```
template<typename T>
struct TrackedAccessor : public T 
{
    operator T &()
    {
        assert( ... ); // catch invalid access
        return *this;
    }

    operator const T &()
    {
        assert( ... );  // catch invalid access
        return *this;
    }

    T &operator=( const T &rhs )
    {
        assert( ... );  // catch invalid access
        return T::operator =( rhs );
    }
    
private:
    // members used to track/control access here
};
```

and changing GlobalStruct to

```
struct GlobalStruct
{
    TrackedAccessor<MyStruct> myStruct;
};
```

This works for the assignment case, and would work if myStruct was being passed into functions expecting a MyStruct*/MyStruct& via the implicit cast, but doesn't work for direct access.

Is there anything I can do to intercept these accesses without changing the calling/user code?

Thanks.

Comment: If you do not want to modify the original `MyStruct` or functions taking a `MyStruct` as type, then there is no way. The behavior of a member access inside such a function is fully determined by the definition of `MyStruct`. Or is modification of `MyStruct` allowed as long as it doesn't require modification of the code using it?

Comment: @user17732522 sorry if that wasn't clear - MyStruct can be modified as long as it doesn't modify the code using it, yes, but is not preferred, especially since this process would be repeated for multiple struct types (hence trying to have some external, re-usable wrapper). But if that's what's required, I'm open to it! If the struct is being modified; the original structs are all "POD" type structs and can't have e.g. inheritance.

Comment: Then you "just" need to implement custom types wrapping `int`, `char`, `float`, etc. with the respective type's interfaces, together with conversion operators to references of the underlying type and replace the members with those. Then, you should be able to catch all accesses, except those made through references to the members, which are impossible to catch. I don't think there is any simpler general solution. It the types are POD, it should be possible to write a single templated wrapper that just forwards all the operators to the built-in ones.

Comment: Just to check @user17732522, by "except those made through references to the members", you mean if a reference is maintained elsewhere? Makes sense. I misused POD - I just mean they're trivially copyable, but the list of members does include user-defined structs and such. There are 10s and 10s of them, meaning a fair bit of churn changing all to wrapped, but sounds like it's the only real option.

The reason this works vs wrapping the outer struct is the casts must occur for those inner members to work, right? Whereas the outer struct's members being accessed isn't a type of (implicit) cast.

Comment: If the code has a function `void f(int& x) { x = 1; }` and it is called by the code with `f(globals->myStruct.a)`, you can trace the conversion to the `int&` reference, but not the actual write. I don't see any way to observe that without changing the calling code. When wrapping the struct itself you have no way of intercepting the `.` member access (it can sadly not be overloaded in any way). This is why you need to wrap the members individually. The whole thing comes with caveats though. It could in some situations change how overload resolution behaves, type traits are affected, etc.

Comment: @user17732522 that makes sense - catching the conversion itself would be perfectly fine. One other complication is if one of the wrapped types is itself a struct with members that can be accessed - sounds like they'd all need to be wrapped too, else it comes back to the original issue of no `.` operator overload.

Comment: It’s worth noting that this question is the precise reason why people say you should use private data members and accessor functions—because you might want to change the behavior someday.  Obviously it’s a judgment call as to whether it’s worthwhile to pay up front to prevent paying later, but it’s worth recognizing that this is that “later”.